# Indexed Families of Sets - Question about demostration

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding the demonstration of the following:

If $\{A_i|i\in I\}$ is an indexed family of sets. Prove that $\displaystyle\bigcap _{i\in I}A_i\in \bigcap _{i\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)$.

This is what I have tried:

Let $j\in I$. If $x$ is an element of $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ then $x\in A_j$. Since $x$ is an arbitrary element of $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$, then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq {A_{j}}$, therefore $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \in \mathscr{P}(A_j)$ but as $j$ is arbitrary, so $\displaystyle\bigcap _{i\in I}A_i\in \bigcap _{j\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_j)$.

From here I have two ideas:

1.Since $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ is mentioned in the statement expression, then every time $i$ is mentioned in the proof then it is done reference to any element $i\in I$, so you could change the $j$ to $i$, and thus you get what you want to demonstrate .

2.Since at the beginning of the demonstration $j$ is named as any element of $I$, no one in particular is being selected, then there is nothing strange about calling it like $k$ or even $i$, and thus you obtain what you want to prove.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me if I am missing something in those "two ideas" to complete the demonstration.

PS: I don't speak Spanish, I hope I wrote it well.

Greetings.

Comment: You already done it, you don't even need the second ideas. I would rephrase a few things but in essence the proof is correct.